# Using write() to create a temporary file in C

Tags: c

For homework I have to read from the standard input, save it to a file and then read the file in another process. However, I'm confused as to why this code does not work:

```
    while((n = read(0,buf,sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
        int tempfile = open("testfile", O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0666);
        write ( tempfile , buf , sizeof(buf) );
        close(tempfile);
        process("testfile");
    }
```

I'm not supposed to use any stdio stuff.

When I look at the file I've created, it has 0 bytes and yet the buffer itself has the correct information....can someone help em see where I've gone wrong?

I can use process on file names and it correctly reads them.

Comment: you should open your outputfile **before** the while loop, and close it after.  The way you're doing it now reinitializes the file on every loop.

Comment: Is there a better way of clearing the data in the file before writing more data every time?

Comment: so you mean this is intentional?  Ie, one read, followed by one write, file is read by another process, etc?  If that's the case what you're doing looks suspiciously like an inter process communication mechanism, and if that's the case I would look at more appropriate mechanisms like pipes or sockets - are you sure you have to clear the temp file every time something is written in it?

Comment: I'm sure I have to, I've not used pipes yet but I look into it,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've specified `O_TRUNC | O_CREAT` for the open flags, but you've failed to specify `O_RDWR` or `O_WRONLY`.

You also probably want to write `n` bytes, not `sizeof(buf)`, as the remaining `sizeof(buf) - n` bytes are uninitialized.

Comment: Pardon me, But I have one more question now that it's working (thanks for helping me with that). When it takes the standard input it keeps grabbing it until I give it an empty line, then it does all the processes at once. Is there any way to make it not do that?